# Junit : How to assign the return value by a method in junit

Tags: java, junit

How can I test this class using mock object:

> class Myclass{
>
> ```
>      MyStudent mystudent=null; 
>      Mymethod mymethod= new Mymethod ();
>
>      public void show(String data){ 
>          mystudent=mymethod.display(data);
>
>      }
>   }
> ```

Here `mymethod.display()` method returns an instance of `mystudent`

Comment: @  tests for a behavior. what is behavior here?

Comment: Hoe to write the test for testMethod

Comment: I don't understand the question: Is the class _Test_ your junit test for another class Totest? is _TestMethod_ a test case? In your answer, there is the word test in every class/object/method, so it's difficult to help you :)

Comment: the class should be..                                                      class test{ 

     Mytest mytest=null; 
     Totest totest= new Totest();

     public void myMethod(string data){ 
         mytest=totest.display(string data);
     }
  }

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you would like an example of a junit test using mocking on a trivial example.
Using Junit4 and [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) your junit test would look like this:

TestTest.java

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;

import org.junit.Before;


public class TestTest {
    private Test test;
    private Totest totest;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        totest = mock(Totest.class);
        test = new Test(totest);
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void mytest_should_not_be_null_after_I_called_displayed(){
        when(totest.display(anyString())).thenReturn(new Mytest());
        test.myMethod("some data");
        assertNotNull(test.getMytest());
    }
}
```

The *setup* method is anotated with the *@Before* annotation. It is executed before any test case from this test class runs. The test case is annotated with *@Test*. It just check that the field *mytest* is non null after the method *display* is called.

And you need to improve your Test class like this:

```
class Test{ 

     private Mytest mytest=null; 
     private final Totest totest;

     public Test(Totest totest) {
         this.totest = totest;
     }

     public void myMethod(String data){ 
         mytest = totest.display(data);
     }

    public Mytest getMytest() {
        return mytest;
    }

 }
```

You should note the constructor, that takes a Totest instance as parameter. the totest field of this class becomes final because the only piece of code allowed to set it is your constructor. This way you can inject any instance of Totest in the Test class. This is some kind of dependency injection (an example of how you can inject dependencies into a class, but there is other ways to do it, you could have used a simple setter as well, I just prefer to declare my dependencies as final because it is clearer in my opinion).
So why did I used DI in your trivial example? Because I needed to inject an instance of Totest inside Test. The instance I inject in the unit test is just a mock. The first line of the test case define the behaviour of the mock instance when displayed is called.

I hope it makes some sence.